# Getting the index and value from a Series

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, append, series

I'm having a bit of a slow moment with selection and indexing in pandas.

I have a Date Time series from which I am trying to select certain elements, along with their date time index in order to append them to a new series.
Example:

```
import pandas as pd

x=pd.Series([11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
for i in range(len(x)):
    print x.ix[i]
```

Gives the output:

```
runfile('C:/Users/AClayton/WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3/python-2.7.5.amd64/untitled6.py', wdir='C:/Users/AClayton/WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3/python-2.7.5.amd64')
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

I would like to have the output

```
1  11
2  12
3  13
4  14
5  15
etc
```

Anyway to get the index too? (I don't just want to print it, I want to append some to a new series. For example, add all the numbers divisible by two to a Series, along with their index).

Sorry if this is obvious, been a long day.

Comment: If speed matters at all, you'll want to avoid using for loops on pandas objects. What criteria are you using to filter down to the last one? Something like `x <= 15` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I have a machine generating a certain amount of power. It has two states, one, the usual steady state, and one where it drops below 400. So I'd be using x<400. Speed is definitely a factor. Basically I'm doing averaging on the data, and need to flag where the data is in the low state so I know not to include it. (This is why I need the index in the new series)

Comment: Have a look at the indexing docs, especially the [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). If you have any trouble it may be best to post  new question.

Answer (score 4):

To get both index and value, you can iterate over series. Note that default index starts from `0`, not from `1`:

```
>>> for i, v in x.iteritems():
...    print i, v
...
0 11
1 12
2 13
3 14
4 15
5 16
6 17
7 18
8 19
9 20
```

Sure you can assign a custom index to a series:

```
>>> x.index = range(1, 6)*2
>>> for i, v in x.iteritems():
...    print i, v
...
1 11
2 12
3 13
4 14
5 15
1 16
2 17
3 18
4 19
5 20
```

Don't completely get what you mean with *"I want to append some to a new series"*, but you can access index with `index` property:

```
>>> x.index
Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='int64')
```

or move it into series, making a dataframe:

```
>>> x.reset_index()
   index   0
0      1  11
1      2  12
2      3  13
3      4  14
4      5  15
5      1  16
6      2  17
7      3  18
8      4  19
9      5  20

[10 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get both index as well as the item:

```
In [4]: import pandas as pd                                                                      

In [5]: x = pd.Series([11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])

In [6]: for ind, item in enumerate(x, 1):                                                        
    print ind, item                                                                              
   ...: 
1 11                                                                                             
2 12                                                                                             
3 13                                                                                             
4 14                                                                                             
5 15                                                                                             
6 16                                                                                             
7 17                                                                                             
8 18                                                                                             
9 19                                                                                             
10 20
```

To get a new series use a list comprehension inside `pandas.Series`:

```
In [25]: indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(x, 1) if v%2]                                        

In [26]: s = pd.Series([(i, x[i-1]) for i in indices], index=indices)            

In [27]: s
Out[27]: 
1    (1, 11)                                                                                     
3    (3, 13)                                                                                     
5    (5, 15)                                                                                     
7    (7, 17)                                                                                     
9    (9, 19)                                                                                     
dtype: object
```

Numpy version:

```
In [53]: import numpy as np

In [54]: indices = np.where(x%2)[0] + 1                                                          

In [55]: pd.Series(np.column_stack((indices, x[indices-1])).tolist(), index=indices)             
Out[55]: 
1    [1, 11]                                                                                     
3    [3, 13]                                                                                     
5    [5, 15]                                                                                     
7    [7, 17]                                                                                     
9    [9, 19]                                                                                     
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, looking at the list comprehension, is there a way to keep the original index as the index? Would I have to use `reindex`?

Comment: @user2761786 Check the updated solution, if you can use numpy then: `indices = np.where(x%2)[0] + 1`