# Access the header/name of items in a pandas.core.series.Series serious

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I have the following code where I'm trying to pull dividends for a stock I own and access the corresponding ex date:

```
def get_all_dividends(ticker):
    yahoo_stock_obj = yf.Ticker(ticker.upper())
    dividends = yahoo_stock_obj.dividends
    names = numpy.unique(numpy.concatenate(dividends.apply(lambda x: [y['name'] for y in x])))
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()


get_all_dividends('psec')
```

I tried to use [accessing unique items from a pandas.core.series.Series dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159392/accessing-unique-items-from-a-pandas-core-series-series-dictionary) but am getting a type error that the object being iterated over is a float not a string:

```
File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 1143, in apply_standard
    mapped = lib.map_infer(
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2870, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "dividends.py", line 67, in <lambda>
    names = numpy.unique(numpy.concatenate(dividends.apply(lambda x: [y['name'] for y in x])))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

This is what I see when I look at dividends in ipython:

[image]

I am doing something like `dividends[-1]` returns 0.12, the most recent special dividend. What I want is to be able to utilize a tuple like `('6-27-2022', 0.12)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189107/getting-the-index-and-value-from-a-series

Comment: yes sorry, that answers my question. my search was too specific that question didnt come up for me. thank you

Comment: duplicate answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189107/getting-the-index-and-value-from-a-series